# EF 6.1 Configuration using Interceptors with WCF

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I am trying to turn on database logging using the interceptor feature that was added in EF 6.1. It works fine when I turn on in a ASP.NET web.config file, but when I trying to use in a WCF service that uses EF 6.1, it gets the following error

Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/DataAccessService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception..The more telling message is from the inner exception: **Unrecognized element 'interceptors'. web.config line 123**)

**NOTE**: based on the first answer, I am providing more elements from the web.config

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
.
.
.
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>

<interceptors>
  <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="C:\tmp\DataAccessLogOutput.txt" />
    </parameters>
  </interceptor>
</interceptors>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: I'd be happy to find out if anyone has used the EF interceptors with WCF.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't register the [Entity Frame Work configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx#Section) that defines `<interceptors>` correctly. In other words do you have this at the top of your config file?

```
<configuration> 
  <configSections> 
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --> 
    <section name="entityFramework" 
       type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> 
  </configSections> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, I had registered the entity framework as your described and as described in the link that you attached. The database calls in the WCF service all run properly until the interceptors are registered by including an interceptor element under the interceptors child section of the entityFramework section. As I mentioned, I use the exact same mechanism for another site where the database calls are part of an ASP.NET MVC website and everything works OK in that case.

Comment: Then all I can think is to check version numbers (which I'm sure you did many times).

Comment: Have you used the logging feature in a WCF service? I am wondering if anyone has it working? I compared version numbers with those in the MVC website where the logging worked. The version number in the web.cofig is ", EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0," and the referenced dll's path is C:\.....\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll. In the MVC web.config the entry is the same.